# pandas geodataframe to shapefile, fixing datetime error

Tags: python-3.x, shapefile, geopandas

I have a geopandas dataframe and I am trying to export it to an ESRI Shapefile.

`herds_projectplan_ply.to_file(gdb_path, layer="test_HERDS_ProjectPlan_Ply", driver="ESRI Shapefile")`

This gives the error: `ValueError: Invalid field type <class 'datetime.date'>`

I look at the schema: `schema = gpd.io.file.infer_schema(herds_projectplan_ply)`

```
{'geometry': '3D MultiPolygon', 'properties': 
  OrderedDict([
    ('hs2_assetid', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_assetname', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_assetclass', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_suitabilitycode', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_phase', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_docnum', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_docrev', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_revdate', 'str'), 
    ('contract', 'str'), 
    ('originator', 'str'), 
    ('createdby', 'str'), 
    ('createdat', 'str'), 
    ('lasteditedby', 'str'), 
    ('lasteditedat', 'str'), 
    ('hs2_supdoc', 'str'), 
    ('projplannm', 'str'), 
    ('sitecode', 'str'), 
    ('activitytype', 'str'), 
    ('reportstatus', 'str'), 
    ('packageid', 'str'), 
    ('uaid_lswsi', 'str'), 
    ('palaeolithic', 'str'), 
    ('mesolithic', 'str'), 
    ('neolithic', 'str'), 
    ('bronzeage', 'str'), 
    ('ironage', 'str'), 
    ('roman', 'str'), 
    ('earlymedieval', 'str'), 
    ('medieval', 'str'), 
    ('postmedieval', 'str'), 
    ('modern', 'str'), 
    ('startdate', 'str'), 
    ('enddate', 'str'), 
    ('validated', 'str'), 
    ('validuser', 'str'), 
    ('validdate', 'str'), 
    ('validcom', 'str'), 
    ('validrev', 'str'), 
    ('oasisid', 'str'), 
    ('oasis_link', 'str')]
    )
}
```

I change the str fields to date:

```
    schema['properties']['hs2_revdate'] = 'datetime.date'
    schema['properties']['createdat'] = 'datetime.date'
    schema['properties']['lasteditedat'] = 'datetime.date'
    schema['properties']['startdate'] = 'datetime.date'
    schema['properties']['enddate'] = 'datetime.date'
    schema['properties']['validdate'] = 'datetime.date'
```

I tried datetime and datetime.date.

From pycharm I can view the series, here are two records: `(0, datetime.date(1999, 12, 4)) (1, datetime.date(1999, 12, 4))`

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Edit:

I tried `herds_projectplan_ply['hs2_revdate'] = pd.to_datetime(herds_projectplan_ply['hs2_revdate'], errors='coerce')` for each of the problem fields, this then returned the error `fiona.errors.DriverSupportError: ESRI Shapefile does not support datetime fields`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, and resolved it by providing my own schema. For me, this question had the answer that solved my issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/281895/changing-shapefiles-field-type-using-fiona

Comment: Probably a bit late to the party here, but your link literally links back to the same page the question is on that you answered - ie people coming to the party late (like me) can't follow the link.

Comment: Oh wow, how did that happen? Probably a had-too-many-tabs-open goof. Fixed it. If you're looking for help with the same or similar issue, I hope this helps.